# Add content as soon <body> starts

Tags: filters, hooks, the-content, body-class

So, what I am trying to do is creating a slideshow plugin that won't require end user to write a single line of code.
I can't use custom posts because I need to keep it simple for the end user.

Is there a hook or a filter that would let me include my php generated code right after the

> body_class() ?

Is it true that the only hook I can use is

> the_content() ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As every theme is different you can't really expect a plugin to know where to put the slideshow in.

As you say the best place would be the content filter if that's where you want it.
If you want it anywhere else you could inject it after using jquery?

Comment: I know that every theme is different but there are also best practice ( like using body_class() or wp_head() or the_content() ). Anyway in 2017 best solution is still jQuery?

Comment: The simplest way I have seen yet is to use a shortcode. When the slideshow is created, display the code to copy / paste by the user and the user pasts it at the place he chooses in a page.

Comment: @mmm yes, the shortcode is the easiest way, but what if the user is so unable that he will mess it up anyway?

Comment: Then do it for them? is this a plugin that will go on the repository of custom plugin just for you?

Comment: if a user is not able to paste a shortcode, he certainly cannot past his username and password then the backoffice will be ease of this calamity.

Comment: @TomWebb It will be free for everyone on the repository but the real aim is a no-profit association with a lot of different wordpress websites everyone hosted and owned by different people so, I can't write the code for everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

The `body_class()` functions also offers a filter, if that's what you're looking for:

```
add_filter('body_class', 'my_body_classes');
function my_body_classes( $classes ) {

    // Your code here

    return $classes;
}
```

However, if you want to add the content *inside* the body right after it starts, that would probably not possible. Unless there is a custom function right after the body tag that can be hooked into, there is no easy way to do this.

You can do a full `preg_replace()` on pages though, but it is most likely costly.